# JavaScript closure issue (I believe) with jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures

I am using the jQuery Accordion, and have two Accordions on a single page. I want to store the selected index of each Accordion in a cookie. To do this, I have the following code (with the jquery.cookie.js library referenced).

```
function accordionsInitAll() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        accordionInit("#accordion1");
        accordionInit("#accordion2");
    });
}

function accordionInit(sAccordion) {
    var accordion = $(sAccordion);
    var index = $.cookie(sAccordion);
    var active;
    if (index !== null) {
        active = accordion.find("h3:eq(" + index + ")");
    } else {
        active = 0;
    }
    $(sAccordion).accordion(
    {
        active: active,
        change: function (event, ui) {
            var index = $(this).find("h3").index(ui.newHeader[0]);
            $.cookie(sAccordion, index);
        }
    });
}
```

Each Accordion section contains links that reference the same page as the jQuery is on (with different parameters). The functions work in that some state is getting saved. The problem is, the behavior seems random. Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes the active element cookie is null when it should have a value, and sometimes the selected index is switched between the two Accordions.

I am stumped, and the only thing that I can think of is that it's a closure issue, with some variable not being captured correctly.

Is this a closure issue, or do I have some other bug that is causing the problem?

Thanks,
Erick

**Edit 11/510 with solution**

The problem turned out to be that for some reason, the cookie library that I was using would sometimes set the same cookie more than once, leading to a situation where there were two cookie values with the exact same key. The cookie right order was not the same as read order, leading to bizarre behavior.

Once I switched the cookie library to http://code.google.com/p/cookies/ I no longer had any problems. Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the HTML, but closures don't simply fail to work sometimes.

Comment: I can paste the HTML if that would help. It's fairly simple, just basic jQuery accordion. What portion of the HTML would be the most helpful?

Comment: I used FireBug to see what is being sent and recieved, and it looks like the cookies are not working correctly. I'm not sure why the problem is occuring, but cookies aren't being sent.

Comment: the problem is: index is not a valid digits! see my example!

Comment: I didn't include code that made sure that index was a valid digit, sorry. Please see your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **DEMO:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/javascript-closure-issue-i-believe-with-jquery-accordion/

**UPDATED**

```
$(function() {
    var accordions = ['dataAccordion', 'regionAccordion'];
    var index,cookie;
    $.each(accordions,function(i, item) {
        cookie = $.cookie(item);
        index = (null !== cookie) ? parseInt(cookie) : 0;
        $acdn = $('#' + item);
        $acdn.accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            fillSpace: false,
            clearStyle: true,
            active: index,
            change: function(event, ui) {
                index = $(this).find("h3").index(ui.newHeader[0]);
                $.cookie(this.id, index, {
                    expires: 10
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

> - **NOTE:** the use of [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Comment: Thanks so much for putting this together. You example code worked perfectly, but for some reason I'm still having issues. To see what I mean, go to http://data.nbr.org/CountryView/Bhutan/2001 and select a different theme (e.g., Trade) and another country (e.g., Canada) and you should see that the selected accordion doesn't persist. Given that your example works, there is something odd going on with mine, and I have no idea what.

Comment: Hi Erick, it don't work cause you are not added to your two accordion the class .accordions, then you need to revise a little your code, you have declared multiple time accordionInit() function, ones in your html and one in your js file, then you are putting the document ready inside a function and thats is wrong! make the changes and let me know, will find a solution for sure! ;) PS you can completely remove your accordion code and replace with mine!

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. I made the changes, using your code to create the accordions. In addition, I added the accordions class to the div for each accordion. I'm still getting the same issue. Thanks for any help!

Comment: ;) here is a copy of your site on my server just copy past it: http://ask.altervista.org/demo/javascript-closure-issue-i-believe-with-jquery-accordion/demo.html

Comment: Thanks! I copied it over, but I'm seeing the same problem. To repro it, go to http://data.nbr.org/CountryView/India/2001, open the north america region, and select canada. Canada loads, but the open region is Central Asia. I'm using IE8, and I'm about to try with other browsers, but I doubt this is browser issue (knock on wood!). Are you seeing the same behavior that I am?

Comment: nop, it work nice with chrome and ie8! try to clean your cache then try again! ;)

Comment: Bloody heck! That seems to have worked. One thing that I've noticed is that it will save the selected theme for a particular country (i.e., it will remember the theme you are on for Canada). But it doesn't save the theme when you switch countries. For example, if I wanted to look at trade and click between countries. It looks like is should (using the this.id for the cookie key). Is there some aspect of cookies that I am missing?

Comment: uhmm, strange behavior, can you alert the cookie var and let me know what it return when you switch city!?

Comment: Finally! I figured it out! The key was that right after the cookie value is retrieved, it is written back into the cookie (thus transforming null into 0). This means that all page visits will set the cookie. Before the cookie was only set when the accordion section was changed. What I figure is that as jQuery sets the active element, the change event is being fired.

At least that is my theory right now. Once I have a full explaination, I will edit my question.

Comment: No problem on the upvote, but the cache was only part of the problem. I've been watching all the interaction of the cookie and site, and in some instances, the cookie value is set twice! The Get request looks like

regionAccordion=0
regionAccordion=3

So the value being read is the first, but the value being written in the second one! I am trying to figure out exactly when that happens. I will likely post a new question once I figure it out. Thanks so much!